# Why do some congregations only make noise at certain occasions of Haman?

Tags: sources-mekorot, purim

Attended a Purim Seudah tonight at a Sephardic shul where most of the attendees are Israeli.  They only made noise during three (maybe four?) times Haman's name was mentioned.  I am aware of the teshuva saying "no noise", but can't find anything explaining "sometimes." Is there a soource for this concept?

Comment: Hi Deborah, and welcome to Mi Yodeya. As it currently stands your post is phrased as a statement rather than a question. Since this is specifically a question and answer site, your post might get closed if there is no clear question contained therein. To prevent this from possibly happening you can [edit] your post to make it into a clear question.

Comment: From memory, there are those who only make noise when there is an extension to the name, such as Haman HaAgagi. However, when the name is used alone there is no name.

Comment: Maybe it's just a compromise to just do a few

Comment: Thanks to both early responders.  I edited to make the question clear and look forwarded to learning more!

Comment: I thought I read/heard last night that Sephardim only do it for the Haman in Shoshanat Ya'akov.

Comment: In my community there's two prevalent customs: to make noise at all of them, and to make noise at only the first and last.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Deborah and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works? Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 5):

There are various customs about making noise [when Haman is mentioned](https://www.torahmusings.com/2009/03/making-noise-at-mention-of-haman/). Since you mention that it occured more than once, it sounds like the Chabad custom.

> While most congregations allow banging each time Haman is mentioned,
>   others have the custom to do so only when his name is mentioned along
>   with an accolade, such as “Haman Ha’agagi” or “Haman
>   Hara”.<sup>38</sup> Some only bang when hearing Haman’s name during
>   the segment which discusses the demise of Haman’s ten
>   sons.<sup>39</sup> Yet others have the custom to do so only at the
>   first and last mention of Haman in the Megilla,<sup>40</sup> or only
>   those references to Haman which discuss his downfall.<sup>41</sup>
>
> <sup>38</sup> Aruch Hashulchan 690:24, Sefer Haminhagim Chabad
>
> <sup>39</sup> Ketzot Hashulchan 690, Nahar Mitzrayim;Purim, Minhagim
>   of Worms 2:259
>
> <sup>40</sup> Ben Ish Chai;Tetzaveh
>
> <sup>41</sup> Emek Bracha Purim p.246

Answer (score 0):

As Sabbahillel mentioned, it may have been based on some pattern.  I have heard of many of those combinations (although I've never heard of only banging for only "Haman Hara", which occurs only once during the Megillah, so definitely wasn't your case).

Most likely, it is one of two options:

1. They banged each time it mentioned Haman...Ha'agagi, which occurs 5 times in the Megillah (3:1, 3:10, 8:3, 8:5, 9:24).
2. What may be happening is that there was an agreement between the Ba'al Koreh and the Gabbaim (or congregation) to only stop at a few "Haman"s to save time, in which case there may be no pattern at all.  I know that I have personally done this a few times.